# Problemas con la depuracion USB / No funciona en android studio

Tags: android-studio

Pues empece a utilizar Android studio, y al configurar mi telefono no funciona.
En el ide ya descargue con el sdk manager "google USB driver".

En el telefono active las opciones de desarrollador.
Al activar la depuracion usb este se queda como cargando pero a la vez activada.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kWg8r.png

Se queda asi, y en las notificaciones me aparece esto:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8FlOq.png

Entonces cuando le doy a run en android studio no me aparece el dispositivo que configure. La configuración también esta en MTP, por lo que la pc si me lo reconoce.

Uso un LG Stylo 3
Android 7.0

Comment: Proba borrando todos los registros de depuracion de tu celular, luego volve a conectarlo en la pc, y verifica que te salga el cartelito de ''permitir depracion de usb por XXXXXX'' y dale aceptar

Comment: Bueno paul la verdad no si esto te sirva. Yo uso un LG al igual que tú y una vez luego de intentarlo todo, leí algo que decía que eligiera la opción "Transferencia de Fotos" en el teléfono y por increíble que parezca me funciono. Espero haberte ayudado Saludos.

Comment: Eres el puto amo luis, con el PTP funciono que raro xd y asi ahora tambien puedo conectarlo via wifi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si tienes wifi en tu pc o mejor dicho un moden que comparta wifi es mas practico depurar por ese medio.

si, tu respuesta es, si.

puedes probar descargando en el telefono adb wifi y lo instala.
en el computador debes saber donde esta la carpeta de platform-tools creo que usualmente esta es donde se guarda por defecto  C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools unas ves lo tengas localizado e instalada la APP debes abrir una terminal.

pulsas window + R y escribes CMD.

Ya con la terminal abierta escribes cd  C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools y Enter

luego escribes abd connect  +  quedando algo asi : 
abd connect 192.168.1.25:5555

luego te vas a android studio y descarga el plugin de ANDROID ADB WIFI
vas a achivo - configuarcion - plugin lo instalas y LISTO.

Comment: te falto adb tcpip 5555 --> primer paso

Comment: Ups!!! Cierto. @LcsGrz

Answer (score 0):

En este caso veo que tu dispositivo esta autorizado para realizar depuración USB, se supone que no debes tener ningún problema:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

te sugiero revocar la autorización y esperar que se muestre nuevamente la autorización en tu dispositivo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

si lo anterior no funciona probablemente el driver no esta funcionando correctamente o el cable tiene algún fallo.